# Returning vector of str after converting to lowercase

Tags: rust

I have a search function from the rust programming book to search for lines matching a pattern (query).

```rust
pub fn search<'a>(query: &str, contents: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    let mut matching_lines: Vec<&str> = Vec::new();
    for line in contents.lines() {
        if line.contains(query) {
            matching_lines.push(line);
        }
    }

    matching_lines
}
```

In the book, it almost rewrites the exact same code to search the same thing but ignoring capitals. I thought it would be more efficient to reuse the same code by calling the function with lowercase parameters.

```rust
pub fn insensitive_search<'a>(query: &str, contents: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    let query = query.to_lowercase().as_str();
    let contents_lower = contents.to_lowercase().as_str();
    search(query, contents_lower)
}
```

This produces the errors

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/lib.rs:25:17
   |
25 |     let query = query.to_lowercase().as_str();
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^         - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |                 |
   |                 creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
26 |     let contents_lower = contents.to_lowercase().as_str();
27 |     search(query, contents_lower)
   |            ----- borrow later used here
   |
```

I understand that this causes the error because the `to_lowercase` function takes ownership and I cannot return this from the function because it will be cleaned after the function returns meaning it is invalid data.

How can I rewrite this so it is valid? Is it better to use `String` here in this case instead?

Comment: This doesn't work since now you are returning pointers to parts of `contents_lower`. However, `contents_lower` is dropped at the end of the function (unlike `contents`). So these pointers would be invalid, and you can''t do this. Returning a array of strings would work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that this causes the error because the to_lowercase function takes ownership

It does not, but it does create a copy of the source in order to lowercase it.

> How can I rewrite this so it is valid?

You can't, because the data belongs to the current function. The only way to return a vector of reference is if the parent passed in a mutable buffer into which you could write the lowercase data, then you could slice *that*. But that's an enormous amount of complexity for the need.

> Is it better to use String here in this case instead?

Yes since that's what `lowercase()` returns.

In other cases, you could use [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) to avoid "paying" for the new ownership, but here that would increase complexity a fair bit and (depending on how long the strings are and the ratio of already lowercase to needing lowercase) you might not even recoup the conditional check: for each input string you'd need to go through the entire thing to check whether it's already lowercase. If so you can return a `Cow::Borrowed` of the original, otherwise you return a `Cow::Owned` of the lowercase string.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only working with ASCII strings, the following solution works:

```
pub fn insensitive_search<'a>(query: &'a mut str, contents: &'a mut str) -> Vec<&'a str> {
    query.make_ascii_lowercase();
    contents.make_ascii_lowercase();
    search(query, contents)
}
```

The strings are changed to their lower case equivalents in place.